# Probability of getting Queen of spades when you draw 3 cards?

Tags: probability, combinations

When you draw 3 cards from a deck, what is the probability of getting a Queen of Spades? I know if I draw one card then the probability would be 1/52.

Comment: Hint: You can use conditioning

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Determine the probability $q$ of NOT getting a Queen of Spades?

The probability that the first card is not a Queen of Spades is $51/52$.

Now the deck has 51 cards. What is the probability that the second card is not a Queen of Spades?

Then $q=\frac{51}{52}\cdot ? \cdot ?$ and the answer to your question is $1-q$.

Comment: @Jerry Lu Can you take it form here?

Answer (score 1):

Just ask yourself the right questions.

As you note, the probability of drawing the Queen of Spades first is $\frac{1}{52}$.

The next question is: what is the probability of not drawing the Queen of Spades, and then drawing her next? It is $\frac{51}{52}\frac{1}{51}$. I leave it to you to do the calculation.

The next question is: what is the probability of not drawing the Queen of Spades, then not drawing the Queen of Spades, and then drawing her next? It is $\frac{51}{52}\frac{50}{51}\frac{1}{50}$. I leave it to you to do the calculation.

The answer to your question is therefore $\frac{1}{52}+\frac{1}{52}+\frac{1}{52}$.

(I think, though I am sure someone will correct me if I am wrong, that this is the principle of linearity of expectation at work. The expected number of Queens of Spades drawn in $n$ drawings is $n$ times the expected number of Queens of Spades drawn in one drawing - and this is true whether or not you put each card back into the pack after drawing it).